# Wait in the function that returns observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

There is function, which loads user details. This function returns observable. It is called from multiple places. To avoid redundant calls I'd like to wait somehow after the first call until the result is loaded. Any idea haw this can be done using RxJs and Angular?

```js
    getUser(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get('/userAuthenticated');
    }
```

The idea is to wait somehow until the first call is completed and save result in the static variable:

```js
    getUser(): Observable<any> {
      if(!this.userIsLoading) {
        this.userIsLoading = true;
        return this.http.get('/userAuthenticated').pipe(
          tap((res: any) => {
            this.userIsLoading = false;
            this.User = res.data;
        }));
      } else {
        // wait until the first call is completed
        return of(this.User);
      }
    }
```

another idea is to define a static variable for the observable.

please help

Answer (score 1):

```
req$ = this.http.get('/userAuthenticated').pipe(shareReplay(1));

getUser(): Observable<any> {
  return this.req$
}
```

You can use the `shareReplay` operator to cache the result after the first (and then only) call to the backend. Any `late` subscriber will get the cached result

You can read more about shareReplay here:
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay

Comment: Every invocation of `getUser` creates a new Observable. `shareReplay` is pointless in your solution.

Comment: @abetteroliver No, you can subscribe that often you want to the result of getUser and you will get the same cached user, if u want another http call is made, call getUser a second time. Maybe there is a better name for "getUser"...

Comment: That's exactly the point: `getUser` is not called just once -> _It is called from multiple places._

Comment: Well, i edit my answer...

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you can:

- Create a new `Observable` property under your service/component, with the [shareReplay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay) operator to avoid calling the API many times and share the result with each one of the new subscribers.
- Return the new `Observable` from the `getUser` function (You can't add the `shareReplay` directly here, because every time the `getUser` is called, it returns a new `Observable` with `shareReplay`, without returning the same one, which won't work in your case).

Try something like the following:

```js
// import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

private userSource$ = this.http.get('/userAuthenticated').pipe(shareReplay());

getUser(): Observable<any> {
  return this.userSource$;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rxjs has the function `firstValueFrom()` which returns a `promise` that you can `await`.

```js
  async getUser(): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    if (!this.userIsLoading) {
      this.userIsLoading = true;
      return this.http.get('/userAuthenticated').pipe(
        tap((res: any) => {
          this.userIsLoading = false;
          this.User = res.data;
        })
      );
    } else {
      await firstValueFrom(this.http.get('/userAuthenticated'));
      return of(this.User);
    }
  }
```